# Printing memory address of pointers to different primitive data types in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, char, memory-address

In C++ could someone clarify

1- In he following code, printing `char*` is displayed as bunch of random characters, but printing `string*` is just an integer address? Why so?

```
int * intptr;
char * charptr;
std::string * stringptr;
float * floatptr;

//printing 
std::cout << intptr << " ,  " << charptr <<  " , " << stringptr << " , " << floatptr << "\n";
```

output:

```
  0x7ffeea2f1a60 ,  ���� , 0x7ffeea2f1a48 , 0x1092d13d4
```

2- `charptr` is a pointer variable painting to part of memory that contains a character. Just for curiosity, how do you print the address of `charptr`?

3- While reading different sources, I came across to this: "The different printing is because of the functions `(i.e. a const char *)` that treat that memory as a sequence of characters". Could someone expand this answer w.r.t the above code?

Answer (score 2):

`char*` is special with regard to printing. The reason is the historical legacy of C, where strings are represented as arrays of characters. So most of the time given a `char*` what you want to do is print the characters it points at.

I don't think you mean print the address of `charptr` (that would just be `cout << &charptr`), I think you mean print the address which is the value of `charptr`. The way to do that is to cast the address to `void*` before printing it.

```
cout << static_cast<void*>(charptr);
```

Your third question is essentially what I explained in the first paragraph above.